# Grid responsive two big more fill space

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

Can someone help me, if I have two blocks to be big fill the space, if more than three be smaller.
I tried doing it with grid.
What I need
[image]

Here is my code:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 6px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(3rem, 45%));

  background: lightgray;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul > * {
  background: black;
  min-height: 3rem;
}

.test >li {
  background:red ;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Full Container</h2>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>

<ul class="test">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: use flexbox. by simply setting flex:1 to the element it's done

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Using flexbox it would be pretty easy to achieve this result as follows:

```css
.container {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 60px;
  min-width: 40px;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
</ul>
```

You can have a minimum width for each of the boxes. If you have this minimum width requirement, you should set ***flex-wrap: wrap*** to the container in order to make it responsive.

**Solution 2**

Using grid you can achieve the same effect using ***grid-auto-columns*** instead of ***grid-template-columns***:

```css
.container {
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: auto;
}

.box {
  margin: 8px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 60px;
  min-width: 40px;
  grid-row: 1;
  list-style: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .box {
    grid-row: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
  <li class="box"></li>
</ul>
```

And for responsiveness you can use a media query, where you set the grid-row to auto for each children in the container.